# Is there a Mac App or command to autoconnect to SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

Right now I'm running a terminal with multiple tabs since I need to ssh into multiple servers to perform different tasks depending on the project. As I said I keep terminal up but it will eventually disconnect or some other hickup requiring me to either login back in or close and reopen terminal (and all my tabs/connections).

I'd like to either:

1. Open terminal type a command like "connect to webserver" and have it run the ssh command with password
2. Install an app that does this sort of thing and maybe has some extra functionality (not sure what that would be). Hopefully the app would auto connect and display windows for each connection I specify.

Comment: Depending on number of servers and what used for, you can change disconnect settings for each so you won't disconnect from inactivity

Comment: please upvote the answer . If you are happy with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use vSSH Lite, Which is free for 2 tabs. Then you have to pay some amount.
Here is the link [vSSH Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/vssh-lite/id791135050?mt=12)

Comment: I went with the paid version since I had 5 connections to manage.

Comment: I use only free version. So don`t  know about paid version. Thanks for the information.